How can I hide the Home button from my Community navigation menu?
I want to remove/hide the Home button on the Navigation menu.  I've tried using this CSS but it's not working for me.   Any ideas on how to hide the Home button?



I figured it out...the CSS I was using was incorrect.   This worked instead:
nav.themeNavContainer ul li:first-child {
display: none;

}
